# bad ELF interpreter

Tags: linux

While trying to install mongo db on my centos 5

```
-bash: ./mongod: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

after command uname -a I am getting this

```
Linux vps.server.com 2.6.32 #1 SMP Thu Sep 22 13:24:07 MSD 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to run a x86_64 (64bit) program on a x86 (32bit) machine.

Go get mongo db install for 32bit, and that'll fix it.